# Linked list syntax

Tags: c, list, linked-list

```
typedef struct  {
 char name [25] ;
 char breed [25] ;
 int age  ; 
 struct animal *next ;
 } animal ;

 animal *ptr1 , *ptr2 , *prior ;
 ptr1 = (animal*)malloc( sizeof (animal) ) ;
 strcpy ( (*ptr1).name , "General" ) ;
 strcpy ( (*ptr1).breed , "Foreign breed" ) ;
 (*ptr1).age = 8 ;


 (*ptr1).next = NULL ;
 prior =ptr1 ;
 printf ("%s\n" , (*prior).name ) ;
 printf ("%s\n" , (*prior).breed ) ;
 printf ("%d\n" , (*prior).age ) ;
 printf ("%p\n" , (*prior).next ) ;
 free (ptr1) ;
 ptr1 = (animal*)malloc( sizeof (animal) ) ;
 strcpy ( (*ptr1).name , "General 1" ) ;
 strcpy ( (*ptr1).breed , "Abroad breed" ) ;
 (*ptr1).age = 24 ;
 (*ptr1).next = NULL ;
 (*prior).next = ptr1 ;
```

Here is the code to draw a linked list.
The whole code when executes shows an error in the last line:

> In function ‘main’:
>   warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Comment: It might help if you point out _where_ you get the error. As it is a compilation error (i.e. not an error from you program, but an error from the compiler about some problem with your code) the error message contains a line number. In the future, please post _all_ messages, complete and unedited.

Comment: Please note that in the last line prior is pointing to a previously freed memory area; this could result in a crash of your program

Comment: Also, why using e.g. `(*ptr1).next` instead of the more normal `ptr1->next`?

Comment: new user tip: it's always good to ASK the question, do not assume people will know exactly what you want to find out. When reporting error messages, you could say something about version of compiler which generated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "tag" name space (the name after the `struct`) and the identifier name space (the one you declare with `typedef`, eg.) are distinct in C.

The easiest, I find, is to always forward declare the `struct` tag and the `typedef` in one go:

```
typedef struct animal animal;
```

From then on you could easily use the `typedef` name even inside the declaration of the `struct`:

```
struct animal {
  ....
  animal* next;
};
```

Comment: Your help and iterations made me sailed through..Thank you Folks.

Comment: @sauravverma, if the answers helped you, please vote them up, and then chose the one that really answered your question and "accept" it.

Answer (score 1):

change your structue definition to this

```
typdef struct Animal_
{
  char name [25];
  char breed [25];
  int age; 
  struct Animal_* next;
} Animal;
```

Without `Animal_` the struct is an anonymous struct, and cannot have a pointer to it.

Comment: There is no need at all for the underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Change your declaration to:

```
typedef struct animal {
    char name [25] ;
    char breed [25] ;
    int age;
    struct animal *next;
 } animal;
```

The structure tag `animal` has been added to the declaration.
You now have the type `animal` an alias for `struct animal`.

Answer (score 0):

`animal` is the name of the typedef, not the struct. Try this instead:

```
typedef struct _animal {
    char name [25];
    char breed [25];
    int age; 
    struct _animal *next;
} animal;
```

Comment: You should never have global names with leading underscores as those are reserved.

Comment: And in this case you don't even need the underscore, `typedef struct animal { ... } animal;` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

That is actually a warning, not an error.
I don't get why are you using (*s).m instead of s->m. It is simpler and more natural.
I don't see function main in your code and the line where you get the error, I suppose all your code except the struct declaration is the function main.
Try declaring your structure like this (you may also need to add a "typedef struct animal", depending on your compiler):
struct animal {
...
animal *next;
};